# Auto generate bootstrap dropdown menu on mouse hover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying generating a dynamic bootstrap 3 dropdown menu for sharing on mouse hover.

See this picture

[image: Dropdown menu]

Instead of creating lots of HTML code I decided to generate dynamic menu. Here is what I have done so far:

### HTML

```
<div class="dropdown dropup" >
    <a href="#" class="open-dropdown" data-link="http://google.com">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li id="link1">Link One</li>
        <li id="link2">Link Two</li>
        <li class="caret"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.open-dropdown').hover(function(){
        $('#link1').html("Share link 1 "+$(this).data('link'));
        $('#link2').html("Share link 2 "+$(this).data('link'));
        $('.open-dropdown').dropdown();
    });
});
```

### Problems

1. It opens the dropdown menu on click not on MOUSE HOVER.
2. I can't place `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">` code outside of `<div class="dropdown dropup">` container. See this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LTk3x/

Answer (score 1):

What about just using some CSS ? :)

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;    
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMp2r/

Comment: @Nifhel why caret position is misplaced? Also did you check my second problem?

Comment: sorry but I really don't get the second problem, could you provide a jsfiddle with an example please? And caret was like that when I included the bootstrap elements, it is the same in the other answer. But it might be working correctly for you if you didn't have this issue before.

Comment: Nope this is the one I created... And I don't see the relation with the second point, or please be more explicit.

Comment: I want to use `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">` outside of the `<div class="dropdown dropup" >` because I want to reuse the dropdown code on unlimited posts. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: But I don't get why you would not be able to reuse it if it's not outside of the dropdown div... So an example would be nice. If you say it is not working you should have some code to show us.

Comment: Looks like my comment didn't update here. I have updated jsfiddle. Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/jason99/LTk3x/

Answer (score 1):

You can change `$('.open-dropdown').dropdown();` by `$('.dropdown-menu').toggle();`

```
$(function() {
    $('.open-dropdown').hover(function(){
        $('#link1').html("Share link 1 "+$(this).data('link'));
        $('#link2').html("Share link 2 "+$(this).data('link'));
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/32xLc/1/

Comment: Thanks @inye have you checked my second problem?

Comment: why you need put the `ul` elemento outside of `div container` ?

Comment: I want to reuse this code on hundreds of posts on a page.

Comment: yes, this dropdown will appear on all sharing links

Comment: I dont understan very well what you want. Maybe you can create a http://fiddle.jshell.net/ example.

Comment: You can not put outside because bootstrap dropdown element have this structure. Maybe if you explain more what you wanto to do.

Comment: maybe you need more dropdown or you need only one but change the li elements.